# New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage failed in Windows 10

Tags: windows, script, powershell

I'm rewriting a small PowerShell application I made several months ago. This application creates a NotifyIcon. Previously I was loading the icon (image) by pointing the script at the image file. Now I'd like to embed the image code directly using Base64 code.

This works perfectly on a Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012R2 machine, but it fails on Windows 10 (updated).

Here is the command that fails and the returned error :

```
New-Object System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage
```

> ERROR: New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

The PowerShell version on the Windows 10 machine, were the command fails :

> PSVersion   : 5.1.14393.187

The PowerShell version on the Windows Server 2012 R2, were the command runs :

> PSVersion   : 4.0

Anyone knows how to make it work on the Windows 10 computer, or how to load the required assembly in the PowerShell session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx) uses the PresentationCore assembly.

Load the assembly: `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore`.

After loading, you should be able to see a list of members with `[System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage] | Get-Member`. If you tried this before the assembly was loaded, you would receive a `TypeNotFound` error.

Now you can create the `New-Object`.